# How to get ActionExecutingContext from HttpContextBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

I'm working on implementing a customized AuthorizeAttribute.  The AuthorizeCore override accepts HttpContextBase.  If user does not have the correct role, then I want to throw an error.  I found some code where I can set the MasterName, ViewName, etc to redirect the user to.  It uses ActionExecutingContext:

```
private void ThrowError(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, string message)
  {
   var ex = new Exception(message);
   var errorInfo = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
   var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(errorInfo);

   filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { MasterName = MasterName, ViewName = ViewName, ViewData = viewData };
  }
```

Is it possible to get ActionExecutingContext from the HttpContextBase passed into AuthorizeCore override?  If not, any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`AuthorizeCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx) method you don't need to perform any redirects. You simply need to use the Http Context to return true or false depending on whether the user is authenticated and authorized. In order to redirect him to an error page you need to override the [`HandleUnauthorizedRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method where an `AuthorizationContext` is passed as argument and you can handle the case. This method will be invoked when `AuthorizeCore` returns `false` so that you can act accordingly.

Comment: I was making it too complicated.  Thanks for the advice.